# OrientationSensor / Inclinometer weird, undocumented sensor reading jump when facing horizon

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10, augmented-reality, virtual-reality

I'm trying to upgrade an app of mine to use Windows 10 Mobile device sensors as a VR device for the pc (like Google Cardboard).
I'm experiencing a problem with the sensor readouts when the device changes from pointing below the horizon to above the horizon (happens for both landscape and portrait, however in this case only landscape is important). A small sketch:
[image: Switch over point causing major sensor reading change]

Raw sensor readouts (pointing downward):

Inclinometer Pitch: -000.677 , Roll: -055.380 , Yaw: +013.978

Now after changing to pointing upward:

Inclinometer Pitch: -178.550 , Roll: +083.841 , Yaw: +206.219

As you can see, all 3 values changed, by a significant amount. In reality only one axis should have changed, roll or pitch (depending on sensor orientation)

I'm 95% sure, this problem didn't exist in Windows Phone 8. I'm unable to find any documentation about this weird behaviour of the sensors and it's stopping me from creating Augmented Reality and Virtual Reality apps.

Here are 2 pictures of the problem:
[image: Pointing downward]
[image: Pointing upward]

Here is the code for this demonstration:

```xml
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource BodyTextBlockStyle}"
                x:Name="output"
                FontFamily="Consolas"
                Foreground="Black"
                Text="test"/>

</Grid>
```

Code behind:

```cs
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    timer = new DispatcherTimer();
    timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(250);
    timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
}

private void Timer_Tick(object sender, object e)
{
    output.Text = "";
    output.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss.fff") + Environment.NewLine;
    Print();
}

DispatcherTimer timer;
public void WriteValue(String desc, String val)
{
    StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
    int length = desc.Length + val.Length;
    int topad = 40 - length;
    if (topad < 0)
        topad = length - 40;
    output.Text += desc + val.PadLeft(topad + val.Length) + Environment.NewLine;
}
public String ValueToString(double value)
{
    String ret = value.ToString("000.00000");
    if (value > 0)
        ret = " +" + ret;
    else if (value == 0)
        ret = "  " + ret;
    else
        ret = " " + ret;

    return ret;
}
public static double RadianToDegree(double radians)
{
    return radians * (180 / Math.PI);
}
public void Print()
{
    WriteValue("DisplayOrientation", LastDisplayOrient.ToString());

    WriteValue("Inclinometer", "");
    WriteValue("Pitch", ValueToString(LastIncline.PitchDegrees));
    WriteValue("Roll", ValueToString(LastIncline.RollDegrees));
    WriteValue("Yaw", ValueToString(LastIncline.YawDegrees));
    WriteValue("YawAccuracy", LastIncline.YawAccuracy.ToString());


    WriteValue("OrientationSensor", "");
    var q = LastOrient.Quaternion;


    double ysqr = q.Y * q.Y;
    // roll (x-axis rotation)
    double t0 = +2.0f * (q.W * q.X + q.Y * q.Z);
    double t1 = +1.0f - 2.0f * (q.X * q.X + ysqr);
    double Roll = RadianToDegree(Math.Atan2(t0, t1));
    // pitch (y-axis rotation)
    double t2 = +2.0f * (q.W * q.Y - q.Z * q.X);
    t2 = t2 > 1.0f ? 1.0f : t2;
    t2 = t2 < -1.0f ? -1.0f : t2;
    double Pitch = RadianToDegree(Math.Asin(t2));
    // yaw (z-axis rotation)
    double t3 = +2.0f * (q.W * q.Z + q.X * q.Y);
    double t4 = +1.0f - 2.0f * (ysqr + q.Z * q.Z);
    double Yaw = RadianToDegree(Math.Atan2(t3, t4));
    WriteValue("Roll", ValueToString(Roll));
    WriteValue("Pitch", ValueToString(Pitch));
    WriteValue("Yaw", ValueToString(Yaw));
}
Inclinometer sIncline;
DisplayInformation sDisplay;
OrientationSensor sOrient;
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    sIncline = Inclinometer.GetDefault(SensorReadingType.Absolute);
    sDisplay = DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView();
    sOrient = OrientationSensor.GetDefault(SensorReadingType.Absolute);
    sOrient.ReadingChanged += SOrient_ReadingChanged;
    sDisplay.OrientationChanged += SDisplay_OrientationChanged;
    sIncline.ReadingChanged += SIncline_ReadingChanged;

    LastDisplayOrient = sDisplay.CurrentOrientation;
    LastIncline = sIncline.GetCurrentReading();
    LastOrient = sOrient.GetCurrentReading();
    timer.Start();
}

private void SOrient_ReadingChanged(OrientationSensor sender, OrientationSensorReadingChangedEventArgs args)
{
    LastOrient = args.Reading;
}

private void SDisplay_OrientationChanged(DisplayInformation sender, object args)
{
    LastDisplayOrient = sDisplay.CurrentOrientation;
}
OrientationSensorReading LastOrient;
InclinometerReading LastIncline;
DisplayOrientations LastDisplayOrient;
private void SIncline_ReadingChanged(Inclinometer sender, InclinometerReadingChangedEventArgs args)
{
    LastIncline = args.Reading;
}

protected override void OnNavigatingFrom(NavigatingCancelEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatingFrom(e);

    sIncline.ReadingChanged -= SIncline_ReadingChanged;
    sDisplay.OrientationChanged -= SDisplay_OrientationChanged;
    sOrient.ReadingChanged -= SOrient_ReadingChanged;
    timer.Stop();
}
```

**edit: Added the following sketch and more description**

Take a look at this following, more in depth sketch:
[image: More indepth sketch]

Position the phone as seen in step (1). Phone in landscape mode, camera facing slightly downward, screen facing slightly upward.

Change to step (2). You slightly tilt it forward, only one axis should change (in this case Inclinometer will show you only "Roll" changing. **THIS IS CORRECT**)

Change to step (3). You now tilt your phone back. As soon as the switch over point comes, where the camera is no longer facing the ground, but now the sky and the screen is now facing slightly downward, all 3 values change by a significant amount. Pitch will jump by about -180°, Roll will jump by about 90° additionally to the amount you actually changed, and Yaw will jump by about +180°.

**As long as the camera is ONLY pointing to EITHER the earth or the sky, the sensors behave fine! ONLY when switch from one to the other does this problem occur! (This scenario happens all the time with VR and AR, so this is a big problem)**

Comment: Have you confirmed this on multiple devices? How do you know it isn't just broken hardware?

Comment: (plus)1 for your sketchy image. :)

Comment: @Liam Yes, happens on a Lumia 920, Lumia 930 and Lumia 950. You can also replicate this in the emulator

Answer (score 0):

> Raw sensor readouts (pointing downward):
>
> Inclinometer Pitch: -000.677 , Roll: -055.380 , Yaw: +013.978
>
> Now after changing to pointing upward:
>
> Inclinometer Pitch: -178.550 , Roll: +083.841 , Yaw: +206.219
>
> As you can see, all 3 values changed, by a significant amount. In reality only one axis should have changed, roll or pitch (depending on sensor orientation)

Your test is not strict. If you want to observe `Roll` and `Pitch`, you should set a stationary coordinate for testing.

I have tested the `Inclinometer` in my physical device. When I slide the phone in the direction of the X axis. All 3 values changed, But only the Pitch value changes most clearly，and the remaining two values are within the error range.

> The [Inclinometer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/sensors#inclinometer) sensor specifies the yaw, pitch, and roll values of a device and work best with apps that care about how the device is situated in space. Pitch and roll are derived by taking the accelerometer’s gravity vector and by integrating the data from the gyrometer. Yaw is established from magnetometer and gyrometer (similar to compass heading) data. Inclinometers offer advanced orientation data in an easily digestible and understandable way. Use inclinometers when you need device orientation but do not need to manipulate the sensor data.

For more you could refer to [Sensors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/sensors).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but unfortunately you missed the most important part: The descripted problem only occurs when pointing the back of your phone to the horizon. Please take a look at my now added, more in-depth sketch and description. If this is not enough to show you the problem, please tell me, and I'll take the time to make a video showing the problem

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Yes, I get the same result in my side. when I did step 3. I has been  consulting related team for this issue. I will keep you posted!